# Don't know name of a sick person's mother

Tags: minhag, tefilla, names, choleh-sick

I suspect that this is a fairly common problem, particularly in Orthodox schuls: one knows someone who is unwell, but comes the מי שברך לחולים, they don't know the choleh's mothers name.

In these instances I have seen two solutions employed: using the father's name, or that of Sarah Imeinu. What is the preferred solution?

Comment: I kinda think we should merge that hither.

Comment: @DoubleAA agreed